# How to decide a value resides in which subtree from a root for a level order binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I have a level order complete binary tree rooted from 2, as in below figure.
[image]

Given a root value and another value v, how can I decide whether v is on left or right subtree of the tree, without traversing the tree?

For example: Let's say root = 2, v = 15. I want to decide using a mathematical function or something that v is in right subtree.

Another example could be, root = 3, v = 10. Answer should be left subtree.

I know I can do this by a tree traversal. I want to know if this is possible in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question if you want O(1) to be the time complexity or space complexity.

But, I assume you are talking about the time complexity as space is abundant these days.

If the space complexity permits, there is an approach using which you can query the subtree with a search value in **constant time**.

The idea is to store all the ancestors of the node with proper direction.

**For example:**

Let's assume `Node 11` to be the target node.

In a single traversal, we can maintain a separate ancestors map for all the nodes containing the respective ancestor and direction to reach the target node.

Starting from the root, `Node 2`.

`Node 2` has no parent, therefore, its ancestors map will be empty.

For `Node 3`, store a key value pair **<2, L>** (`2` for parent and `L` for left).

Likewise, for `Node 4`, store a key value pair **<2, R>** (`2` for parent and `R` for right).

For `Node 6`, the ancestors map looks like:

```
{
    2 : "L",
    3 : "R"
}
```

Repeat the procedure for until we cover each node.

Now, the ancestors map for `Node 11` will look like as follows:

```
{
    2 : "L",
    3 : "R",
    6 : "L"
}
```

Just check if the value of the root of the subtree is present in the ancestors map of `Node 11`.

If present, just return its value, which denotes the left/right subtree, in constant time.

**PS:** Using `unordered map` can be beneficial in such case.

Also, as it is a binary tree, the maximum height for `N` nodes, will be log2(N).

Therefore, **space complexity** required is `O(N * log2(N))`.

The time complexity to for insertion into unordered map is O(1) on average.

Therefore, **time complexity for building all the maps** = O(N * log2(N) * some constant factor).

**Time complexity for queuing** = constant ~ O(1).

For, **N <= 10^5**, the logic for building the ancestors map can be executed within 1 second.